# OSX Finder: Big file count problem / File Limit problem

Tags: macos, ntfs, finder, hfs, afp

Now I deleted question like that.. earlier because I thought deleting of .DS_Store would help... But I still have a hard to live with big file count in one directory.

Don't ask me why everything is in one dir, it can't be another way. I constantly getting many files every week, and I have some renaming program on mac, which - after renaming, if duplicated file name is found, can add "[1]" to the end of the file. This is quite hard to do with having multiple directories and it's time consuming procedure you know..so having all files in one dir saves my time.

Now... I own 300gb storage in here, which plugs thru USB. When I opening this directory it takes 20 SECONDS to show file listing. Same goes from shell.. I even tried to move those files to network device, this time OSX creates some .AppleDouble dir which lags even more then it was before. USB hdd have NTFS and network device FFS through AFP protocol.

I can't stand this anymore please what's wrong is this OSX issue some filesystem limit or what? My friend having even more files then I do (yeah it's whole karaoke database) even more.. and it's fine in windows with total commander.. he have no lag at all you know..

Comment: How many files are you dealing with? What filesystem are you using to store them? Are you really using NTFS to store files that you primarily access on a Mac? Why? If it is taking so long to list the files, then maybe having them all in one directory is no longer saving you as much time as you thought it was. If so, you should consider updating your “renaming program” so that it can handle a whole hierarchy.

Comment: I wrote everything already. Im using USB HDD with NTFS PARTITION. why im using usb hdd? because I have no space on my mac (not 160gb for mp3 files sorry). "renaming program"? im talking about file listing at all, when opening finder or when going thru shell Application->Utilities->Terminal->cd /Volumes/Storage/karaoke->lag for 10-20seconds.

Comment: I never asked why you were using a USB disk, I asked why you were using NTFS to store files that you were primarily accessing on a Mac; NTFS is not a usual filesystem for a Mac, I would not be surprised if there were performance issues with the NTFS driver. I also asked how many files you were dealing with. You mentioned a “renaming program” as a reason you could not move away from a single directory. I was suggesting that you could update or replace this “renaming program” to cope with multiple directories as an alternative solution to storing everything in a single directory.

Comment: @Chris, good point. Spotlight may also be trying to index the drive.

Comment: renaming program doesn't give any problems with renamings at all. I just can't open directory in finder. I'm using ntfs because  this hdd is being accessed by all 3 os'es (linux, win, mac) very often. so this probably is Ntfs driver issue... i hope. spotlight is turned off in here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here's some details what I've found out.

problem is ntfs driver, which OSX using for example i'm using "paragon" company ntfs driver.. so yes it's lagging as hell.. On windows it's ok.. so if anybody tried my situation with other ntfs drivers ant it works please leave some feedback=)